# Java CompletionService multithreading - How to map response to request

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, completion-service

I have bulk requests and would like to use `CompletionService` to concurrently get responses. Here is my code

```
ExecutorService myThreadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
CompletionService<FeeEstimationResult> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(myThreadPoolExecutor);
for (final MyRequest myRequest : myRequestList) {
    completionService.submit(() -> getMyResponse(myRequest));
}
              
for (MyRequest myRequest : myRequestList) {
    try {
        MyResponse myResponse = completionService.take().get();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

How can I know which request that `myResult` is related to? Will `Future` help?

Comment: I guess that `MyRequest` and `MyResponse` should share a common id which would be the key to connect each other.

Comment: There is even a design pattern for it: Asynchronous Completion Token. https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/ACT.pdf